# Active Admin filter params passed to ransacker

Tags: mysql, arrays, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I am trying to pass a couple IDs through to a custom ransacker filter for active admin

```
   filter :hasnt_purchased_product_items_in, as: :select, collection: -> { ProductItem.all }, multiple: true
```

The ransacker code

```
ransacker :hasnt_purchased_product_items, formatter: proc { |product_id|
    users_who_purchased_ids = User.joins(:orders => :items).where("orders.status = 'success'").where("order_items.orderable_id IN (?)", product_id) # return only id-s of returned items.
    ids = User.where.not(id: users_who_purchased_ids).pluck(:id)
    ids.present? ? ids : nil # return ids OR nil!
} do |parent| # not sure why this is needed .. but it is :)
    parent.table[:id]
end
```

This works for a single query but not for multiple, the SQL is doing 2 separate searches instead of one

It's running the following 2 statements

```
order.items.orderable_id IN ('90')
```

and

```
order.items.orderable_id IN ('91')
```

in 2 separate SQL statements, instead of what i want which is

```
order.items.orderable_id IN ('90','91')
```

the submitted info from the active admin page is

```
q[hasnt_purchased_product_items_in][]: 90
q[hasnt_purchased_product_items_in][]: 91
```

i think i need to do something to the incoming parameter at the ransacker stage but i'm not sure how to deal with that

Comment: Have you checked that `params[:q][:hasnt_purchased_product_items_in]` is an array as you'd expect?

Comment: the nature of that ransacker line - proc { |product_id| } means that i'm automatically stepping into the array and retreiving the value, which is why its running the SQL line twice. - maybe if there is a way to submit the id's as a string?

Comment: Yeah but it _shouldn't_ be stepping in. The param should be `|product_ids|` and give us an array object inside the proc that then gets used. I'll post a couple of ideas as answers and delete if they don't work.

Comment: using _in causes a noMethodError - undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be stepping in. The param should be |product_ids| and give us an array object inside the proc that then gets used. Your ransacker should return an active record association or an arel query.

I would try each of these:

1. Use "_in" in the ransacker name, which bypasses the array logic.

```
ransacker :hasnt_purchased_product_items_in do |product_ids|
  users_who_purchased_ids = User.joins(orders: :items).where(orders: {status: 'success'}, order_items: {orderable_id: product_ids}) # return only id-s of returned items.
  User.where.not(id: users_who_purchased_ids)
end
```

2. Same ransacker name, but with block use rather than formatter.

```rb
ransacker :hasnt_purchased_product_items do |product_ids|
  users_who_purchased_ids = User.joins(orders: :items).where(orders: {status: 'success'}, order_items: {orderable_id: product_ids}) # return only id-s of returned items.
  User.where.not(id: users_who_purchased_ids)
end
```

I've had to guess the object to return because it's not clear which model this ransacker is on. If you can tell me the objective (e.g. filtering product recommendations for a user to exclude their purchases) then I can update the answer.

3. Create a scope and make it available to ransack.

User.rb

```
  scope :hasnt_purchased_product_items_in, ->(product_ids){
   users_who_purchased_ids = joins(orders: :items).where(orders: {status: 'success'}, order_items: {orderable_id: product_ids}) # return only id-s of returned items.
   where.not(id: users_who_purchased_ids)
  }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    %i(hasnt_purchased_product_items_in)
  end
```

Then this works:

```
User.ransack({hasnt_purchased_product_items_in: [[1,2,3]]}).result
```

Note that the ransack want's an array of args. We want one arg, which is an array.

Comment: i get a noMethodError undefined method 'klass' for nil:Nilclass - related to the ransacker for using the _in option

Comment: i can't  seem to use the block rather than the formatter as i need the , "splat_params: true do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end" part - this is being returned to ActiveAdmin

Comment: objective is to return users who have not purchased specific items

Comment: I've added a third option which uses scopes and I tested locally. The only thing left would be to ensure that the params you pass through are an array of ids within an array.